# TFS 2015 Update 3 Continuous Reboot Deploy Visual Studio Test Agent Task

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have configured the Visual Studio Test Agent task and its execution causes the machine to continuously reboot. I have AutoLogon enabled and my build agent is correctly configured to be interactive so I can run Coded UI Tests. The only time it will not cause the machine tot reboot is if I am logged into the machine through my RDP session.

Anyone had this problem?

Comment: Is the test agent deployed successfully after continuously reboot? Are you able to reproduce this issue on another machine?

Comment: No Its not deployed successfully. I just keeps rebooting. I have been able to reproduce on alternate machines.

Comment: Can you share the logs of Visual Studio Test Agent task?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, test agent machine will reboot only once when test agents is installed. You can try to download the test agent from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) and install it manually(Expand `Tools for Visual Studio 2015`, and download `Agents for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3`) to see whether the machine would continuously reboot.

If the test agent has deployed on the machine, `Visual studio test agent deployment` task will skip installing test agent.

Comment: I gave it a try, unfortunately it still didn't work. The agent deployed successfully, but the reboot is still occurring. It is failing on the "ConfigureTestAgent" function. It does skip the part where the agent is deployed.

Comment: Here are the logs  
[DTAExecutionHost](https://1drv.ms/u/sAmCjVC8ZdUqojxsvlVtnh8kUsKxG)  
[Build Agent](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmCjVC8ZdUqojxob6C8b9zr_zFOI)

Comment: @Mike, the log file can't be opened, could you re-attache it?

Comment: Thank you for your help. [DTA Execution Host](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqrvo3fm76hc8f4/DTAExecutionHost.exe.log?dl=0)

Comment: Here is the [Build Agent Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ynspe62q0l7bwz1/Build%20Agent%20Log.log?dl=0) as well.

Comment: I have provided  the logs. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mike, the log indicates "CANCELED: System.OperationCanceledException: Task DeployVisualStudioTestAgent was canceled during excution." Could you share us a screenshot of your build definition and how do you set Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task?

Comment: I re-ran the build. I started at 12:28 and just pulled the log file at 20:25. The link to the updated log file is below and also screen shots of the build definition. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: [DTA Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4klgyjzrqlmt5k8/DTAExecutionHost.exe.log?dl=0)

Comment: [Build Definition Image 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uf66h487o7u4qgv/BuildDef1.png?dl=0)

Comment: [Build Definition Image 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdk1911uen79c20/BuildDef2.png?dl=0)

Comment: Also, the build agent is running as a process and not as a service

Comment: Try to the same credentials for the Test Agent as the Build Agent to see whether it will fix your issue. Refer to this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2023

Comment: I did give that a whirl and still no success. It seems to me like it gets tripped up trying to login to the system. Are there any specific group policies that I need to verify?

Comment: I have an updated build log. It looks like the machine keeps rebooting because it cannot find an active desktop session. I looked at the powershell script that is executing and the error code being returned is 3010. Here is the [log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7024w1jtunj4bo/7_Deploy%20TestAgent%20on%20ACTS-DATADEV.ai-engsvcs.com.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Do you try to configure a new build agent and deploy test agent on a new machine? Do you get the same error? Can you try running the deploy test agent task with "interactive process" box as unchecked. Let me know if it passes.

Comment: I have tried that and I get the same behavior on another machine. As for running with "interactive" unchecked, I have done that and everything succeeds.